# How can I remove the 'u' character from the written file?

Tags: python, unicode

I am printing lists into a file using the following code.

```
for i in range(len(testing_data)):
    predicted_tags = tagger2.tag(testing_data[i])
    f.write(str(i)+"\t"+str(unicode(predicted_tags))+"\t"+
            str(unicode(testing_data[i]))+"\n")
f.close()
```

When the data is written to the file, I get the `u` characters. For example:

```
0   [((u'The', u'DT'), 'NN'), ((u'Czech', u'JJ'), 'NN'), ((u'dam', u'NN'), 'NN'), ((u'ca', u'MD'), 'NN'), ((u"n't", u'RB'), 'NN'), ((u'be', u'VB'), 'NN'), ((u'operated', u'VBN'), 'NN'), ((u'*-69', u'-NONE-'), 'NN'), ((u'solely', u'RB'), 'NN'), ((u'at', u'IN'), 'NN'), ((u'peak', u'NN')]
```

How can I get rid of the `u` characters?

Comment: That's what you get when you call `str` on a list or tuple. You need to write out the strings by themselves.

Comment: The line of data you show as written to the file must be incomplete because it doesn't match what the `f.write()` statement would produce.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f.write(str(i)+"\t"+predicted_tags.encode('utf-8')+"\t"+testing_data[i].encode('utf-8')+"\n")
```

Comment: predicted_tags is a tuple. You cannot call `encode` on a tuple directly w/o iteration.

Comment: f.write(str(i)+"\t"+predicted_tags[i].encode('utf-8')+"\t"+testing_data_with_tags[i].encode('utf-8')+"\n")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0):

You could format the `predicted_tags` in first part like this:

```
from operator import methodcaller
utf8 = methodcaller('encode', 'utf-8')

for i in range(len(testing_data)):
    predicted_tags = tagger2.tag(testing_data[i])
    f.write(str(i)+"\t"+
            '[{}]'.format(', '.join('(({!r}, {!r}), {!r})'.format(
                                utf8(tag[0][0]), utf8(tag[0][1]), utf8(tag[1]))
                                    for tag in predicted_tags)))
```

and something similar for `testing_data[i]` in the part following the second `'\t'`.